# InDesign: Anchored Object at the Top of a Page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I'm trying to lay out a textbook.  There are several cases where an image should be at the top of the page, before any text, like this:

[image: Screen shot of InDesign page with image at the top.]

That one is not anchored, but needs to be so it'll stay put, and also so that it will be included with surrounding text in the ePub version.

I've read [this question and answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21291/indesign-can-i-float-an-anchored-frame-to-the-top-of-a-column).  The answer is, "Can't be done" but that was almost ten years ago.  I'm using InDesign 2023. Is there now a way to make this happen?

Comment: Reminds me of [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/134218/84899).

Comment: @Wolff  Interesting.  Thank you.  I'm beginning to believe that Adobe should go all the way back to the drawing board with anchors.

Comment: @Wolff  For full-width objects, such as in my example.  That's the answer!  Thank you!